# Cannot load image path

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, path

I am learning TensorFlow and I am trying to build a neural network that would be able to analyze movie posters. I have downloaded this training dataset https://github.com/laxmimerit/Movies-Poster_Dataset
into my computer and I am trying to open and analyze each of the files in for loop

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization, Conv2D, MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tqdm import tqdm
from pathlib import Path

X = []
for i in tqdm(range(data.shape[0])):
    print(i)
    data_folder = Path("Images")
    img = image.load_img(data_folder, target_size =(IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT,3))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255.0
    X.append(img)
x = np.array(X)
```

Here are full paths to both the folder with images and where my .py file is located:
C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Movies-Poster_Dataset-master\Images
C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Movies-Poster_Dataset-master\Network.py

and this is the error I got:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Peter\\Documents\\Movies-Poster_Dataset-master\\Images'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this seems to be working:

```py
import os

data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT = 350 , 350

X = []
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/Peter/Documents/Movies-Poster_Dataset-master/Images"):
    print(file)
    path = "Images/"+file
    img = image.load_img(path, target_size =(IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT,3))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255.0
    X.append(img)
x = np.array(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the image opened in another program? Sometimes different programs lock access to the file while it's loaded.